# Calling a controller's method before loading/accessing anything in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, hook

I would like to know how can we access a particular method name before loading anything? I have stored user cookies and would like to access before anything any controller or method is accessed to check for authentication. 
e.g.Login cookies are stored and I would like to access only for the very first time so construct is of no use here. I have put the method name in default_controller but it checks only when I access that default_controller page.

I think, hooks can help me but again how to access that controller from hook file? Somebody also mentioned My_Controller but not sure how it would access it.

Thanks.

Comment: You can with core classes for example create `/core/My_Controller.php` and extend your class with `My_Controller` like `class dashboard extends My_Controller` and in `My_Controller construct` do anything what you want

Comment: With this approach I have to extend all the classes. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, all of you have. You can split front and backend class. For frontend classes extend `core/Public_Controller` and backend classes `core/Admin_Controller`.

Comment: Any other way? I have lots of classes so this will be hectic.

Comment: BTW, how can I access login controller's method in My_Controller or do I have to write same method in My_Controller?

Comment: do you explain what you want exactly? Why you try access controller for cookie?

Comment: And I am looking only for the very first time and not in all the controllers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55917/discussion-between-chopra-and-bora).

Comment: My solution would be to create a `user library` and put it in `autoload.php`. That's it!

Comment: I am trying to access controller for cookie because that cookie will then call model and will execute the other things. Can we discuss this in chat?